# Lost ActiveWorksheet after 'for each worksheet' loop

Tags: excel, vba, office-2016

Routine using for each worksheet loop to unprotect all worksheets in workbook, change active worksheet at least instead to keep the actual one.
This behaviour recognized by Office2016 only, and routine start by command button. If you start by Makro, by Event or Immediate window it works fine and ActiveWorksheet keep as it is.
If you put debug stop mark into the routine it will work also fine started by command button.
This behaviour is recognized only by unprotect function. Protect function, print worksheet names or what ever works fine using for each worksheet loop.

It is important to keep ActiveWorksheet.
The function works fine for several years by Office2010.
The issue comes up by change to Office2016. And now we have one sheet the function is called by command button, not by event, and we recognized the issue first time.
To change the function is not so easy because it is used within a validated environment

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.ProtectContents = True Then
        ws.Unprotect Password:=GetPassword()
    End If
Next ws
```

this code will keep ActiveWorksheet for example:
(called by command button)

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.ProtectContents = False Then
        ws.Protect Password:=GetPassword()
    End If
Next ws
```

What do I have to do to keep ActiveWorksheet?

```
'code to reproduce the issue

'declaration zone
Public Const GLB_PW = "Password"

'Module 1
Sub Protection_On()  'called by command button
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not ws.ProtectContents Then
        'ws.Protect GLB_PW  '
        ws.Protect Password:=""
        End If
    Next ws
Debug.Print "Aktive Worksheet: " & ActiveSheet.Name
End Sub
Sub Protection_Off()  'called by command button
'code generating the issue
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.ProtectContents Then
        'ws.Unprotect GLB_PW
        ws.Unprotect Password:=""
        End If
    Next ws
Debug.Print "Aktive Worksheet: " & ActiveSheet.Name
'ActiveSheet moved from Sheet1 to Sheet3
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: What I have to do to keep ActiveWorksheet

Comment: What do you mean to "keep ActiveWorksheet"?

Comment: If you run the loop as mentioned, the ActiveWorksheet will keep as it is. Only running loop to unprotect all worksheets, started by command button, ActiveWorksheet change to last Worksheet in Workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code should not change the active worksheet at all. But what you can do is remember the ActiveSheet in a variable, run the code and then re-activate the sheet again.

```
Dim OriginalActiveSheet As Worksheet
Set OriginalActiveSheet = ActiveSheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.ProtectContents = False Then
        ws.Protect Password:=GetPassword()
    End If
Next ws

OriginalActiveSheet.Activate
```

Comment: That's right. But for this I have to change a high amount of Excel Sheets. These Sheets are used in a validated environment. Document and Test Activities would be very high. And the question is, why this behaviour comes up by unprotect sheet only? Only if you start the code by command button?

Comment: @user11255039 If you have more than one workbook open at a time it is probably because `ActiveWorkbook` is not what you expect it to be. `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook that has the focus (that is on top) while the code is running. Any click or other interference can easily chang which workbook is the active one. You probably should have used `ThisWorkbook` instead, which is the workbook this code is running in (and cannot be changed by any user interaction).

Comment: Actually I cannot reproduce your issue in a new created workbook. So please run your code step-by-step using F8 and see at which point exactly your active sheet changes. Maybe you can find any specific reason this way.

Comment: ActiveWorkbook or ThisWorkbook solve not the issue, the behaviour is still the same.

Comment: For reproduce please start function by command button. Please don't use debugger stop marks in code or step by step function in code. The issue comes up by unprotect routine only.

Comment: @user11255039 I created a new workbook, added 2 buttons to Sheet1, added your code in 2 procedures (`Sub DoProtect` and `Sub DoUnProtect`) linked the buttons to these procedures and clicked them. Sheet1 stays active whatever button I click. • Try the same.

Comment: @Peh, I created a new workbook as you mentioned. Added 4 Worksheets. On the first worksheet I added two buttons as you mentioned, and if I push the button for DoProtect, the active Sheet keep as it ist, if I push the button DoUnProtect the active Sheet move to Sheet3.

Comment: That is actually strange. The code does not change the active sheet at all. Does it work if you replace it with `Password:=""`? That's the only thing I changed.

Comment: @Peh, I changed code as you mentioned and active sheet move to sheet3 in the same way like before. Shall I provide the code is use?

Comment: @user11255039 yes please add it in your orginal question.

Comment: @Peh, I added trial code as mentioned.
Please keep in mind I'm using Excel Version 2016 MSO(16.0.8431.2270). In Excel 2010 code works fine every time.

Comment: @user11255039 yep, got it reproduced now with your code. Actually this must be a bug in Excel. Since it always activates the second last worksheet (which does not even make any sense at all). The code should definitly not change the active sheet. The only solution I see at the moment is to do the workaround I mentioned above, report the bug to the Microsoft Support and wait for them to fix it. • I tested it on Excel 2016 MSO 16.0.11328.20220 64-Bit which is the latest update and still shows the same issue. *(Actually I couldn't reproduce it at first with only 2 sheets because it works then.)*